**How to get colored prediction output in multi class unet segmentation**
i have the same data and annotation just like show in the provided link,
U-net: how to improve accuracy of multiclass segmentation?
query : why i didnot get the colored output prediction, i have the same task which he did in the provided link (please go through), i.e i get one same gray color of all segmented objects
How to get per-class probability etc you can provide me the prediction code also.
Response would be appreciated, Thank you
